# Does any way to show Line chart on Y2 Axis in MS Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart, linechart

I would like to use Multiple Y-Axis in Line chart of MS-Charts.

I have multiple series in Line chart. Now, I want to show some of these series on Y-Axis and others on Y2-Axis.

can anyone advise how can I implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a good library for creating charts.

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Try this link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168056/Windows-Charting-Application

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer myself.

there are two Axis Types are available. For Y2 Axis We have to use Following line of code.

```
 series.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```